REDCap - How to delay text appearance within a section of a survey for a few seconds?
Without using CSS/JS, how do you delay the appearance of text as well as a multiple choice question within a section of a survey for x number of seconds, in which upon opening that section, the user would see the text and MCQ appear after x seconds.
Alternatively, is there any way to delay the appearance of the "Next" button on a section for x seconds? The user shouldn't be able to begin the next section right away if they wanted, and would need to wait x seconds for the Next button to appear.
CSS/JS/any external injection is not an option. Considered some external modules but they don't exactly achieve what I've described I think. Ideally there should be a delay that can be coded such that it appears after x seconds, be it text + MCQ or the "Next" button.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
